# Write multi-line string to SQL Server using C# ADO.NET?

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I am trying to write a multiline text to SQL server database. Each line is terminated with "\r\n" but the text is saved in SQL Server with no line break so when I copy column value from SQL server management studio  it is just one sentence 
"lineone line2 line3" with no line breaks.

**Why is the line break is removed?**

```
string cnnString = null;
    Sqlcnn cnn ;
    SqlCommand cmd ;
    string sql = null;

    cnnString = "Data Source=ServerName;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;User ID=UserName;Password=Password";
    sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_AnswerSelected (AnswerValue) VALUES (@AnswerValue) ";

    cnn = new Sqlcnn(cnnString);
    try
    {
        cnn.Open();
        using (var sqlCommand = cnn.CreateCommand())
        {
            sqlCommand.CommandText = sql;

             command.Parameters.Add("@AnswerValue", SqlDbType.String);
             command.Parameters["@AnswerValue"].Value = "lineone\r\nline2\r\nline3\r\n";

            return sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you trying to view it in SQL Studio or actually retrieving the values? SSMS replaces line breaks with spaces in the grid output.

Comment: Unclear what you mean when you say " when I copy the string from SQL"

Comment: Make sure the option `Retain CR/LF on copy or save` is checked, otherwise as you have seen, they are replaced, now when you copy you should get the carriage return/line feeds.

Comment: https://beeming.net/data/2016/7/ssms-2016-where-have-my-line-breaks-gone / https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/187680/carriage-return-line-feed-stopped-working-in-sql-server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for your comments. it seems the problem is in SQL management studio because if I copy the column value from SQL management studio the end of line will not show. I wrote a c# app to read the record from the SQL database and the string included the end of line character.